# Extracting interfaces with complex class structure

Tags: c#

I am a bit confused about the best way to use interface extraction when I have multiple layers of classes and interfaces. Suppose I have the following hierarchy:

```
Foo : WidgetBase, IWidget 
WidgetBase: BusinessObject, IThingy
IThingy : IGenericObject
```

Now I know I have to extract an IFoo interface into a separate project; but does that interface structure have to replicate the real structure - meaning that I would have to extract interfaces for BusinessObject and WidgetBase too? Or does it mean that I should flatten the structure when creating extracted interface, creating 1 interface, IFoo, containing properties corresponding to the properties of Foo AND all of its parent classes and interfaces, all the way up the hierarchy?

There are also some enum type properties in my interfaces - how can I best tackle those?

```
public interface IWidget
{
    public WidgetType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum WidgetType
{
    Big, Small
}
```

Please shed some light.

Comment: perhaps looking at this MSDN site about Explicit Interface Implementation may help illustrate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimum requirements for `IFoo`**

`IFoo` should inherit `IWidget` and `IThingy`.
It also needs to include all public members of `Foo` and `WidgetBase`.

```
public interface IFoo : IWidget, IThingy
{
    // public member of Foo and WidgetBase...
}
```

**Potential refactoring 1:**

It would probably be better to define an interface for `WidgetBase` like this:

```
public interface IWidgetBase : IThingy
{
    // public members of WidgetBase...
}
```

then `IFoo` could just inherit that:

```
public interface IFoo : IWidget, IWidgetBase
{
    // public member of Foo.
}
```

**Potential refactoring 2:**

The same could apply to `BusonessObject`: define an interface for it, and have `IWidgetBase` inherit that.

**General principal:**

Your interfaces should specify the behaviours of your objects, and should use inheritance where behaviours are naturally extended.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend that depending on your purpose of the new interface. What behaviors you want the IFoo to have? In other word, what is it used for in the new project. Extract just enough for the new project. Do not mess up your IFoo with the inheritance from other interfaces or from the current state of Foo class.